# childNodes list is empty before page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom

```
// Some jQuery to load the HTML file
$(function(){
  $("#myDiv").load("./someHTMLfile.html");
});

var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
console.log(div.childNodes);
console.log(div.childNodes[0]); // Prints undefined
```

When this code runs, the list `div.childNodes` is empty, but when I check the variable in the Chrome console, the list is not empty. Chrome also tells me that **"Object state below is captured on first expansion"**.

When I execute `console.log(div.childNodes[0])` in the Chrome console, it returns the first element, as it should. I've also tried to make the script execute after the page is fully loaded with `jQuery $(document).ready()`, but it didn't solve anything.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: *"Why is this"* You are accessing the element before it was populated. *"how do I fix it"* Wait until it is populated. See the documentation of load: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` runs asynchronously, plus you've wrapped it in the jQuery ready function.  All this means that `console.log(div.childNodes)` is running well before `someHTMLfile.html` has been loaded and inserted.

What you need to do is use the callback function available in `load` to run any functionality that depends on the html:

```
$(function(){
  $("#myDiv").load("./someHTMLfile.html", function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    console.log(div.childNodes);
    console.log(div.childNodes[0]);
  });
});
```